# How to delete the first few lines of data and a specific matching numeric number until the very end of data

Tags: text-processing, sed

```
51 0 0 5  
0 0.0 0.0 0  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
1, 2  
0.998 0.567  
3, 2 Rs12345  
0.7 0.2  
3, 2 Rs31256  
0.56 0.311  
3, 2 Rs25691  
0 0  
012.1313010310 0.1213212 0.2121331321
0.0121654564 0.254564564 0.25678646 
0.02154 0.2485674354 0.2434
```

The resulting output should look like this

```
3, 2 Rs12345    
0.7 0.2  
3, 2 Rs31256  
0.56 0.311  
3, 2 Rs25691
```

I used the sed to achieve the desired result

```
sed -i -e '1,5d;/0 0/,$d' filename
```

This did not work. I am dealing with multiple files like this that have different lengths in the number of lines. Therefore, I will have to somehow get rid of the "0 0" and every line after that (very end of data)

Comment: I'm afraid you will have to reword this; I can't understand what you want, or how the result doesn't match your expectation ...

Comment: @tink I only want the data that is after the first 5 lines and before the "0 0". Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 0):

You had it ALMOST right ...

```
sed -e '1,5d;/^0 0/,$d' genetics 
3, 2 Rs12345  
0.7 0.2  
3, 2 Rs31256  
0.56 0.311  
3, 2 Rs25691
```

Just add the -i back in if this is what you want

Comment: @don_crissti, that may well be, but there's nothing to say that any of their other files doesn't have '0 0' on one of the lines that have valid data in front of it.

Comment: @don_crissti: and I didn't say the anchor was what made it right; it's the same ' you added into the original post ;}

Comment: don - they didn't say in what way it didn't produce the desired result. It may well have been a sed error?

Comment: @don_crissti that may well be, but there's nothing to say that any of their other files doesn't have '0 0' on one of the lines that have valid data in front of it. <- this is very well a possibility

Comment: @tink your solution worked when I added the "-i" back in. Thanks so much

Comment: Sweet :) ... please feel free to accept it ;}  Bare in mind that you may need a terminating anchor on the '0 0' line as well  -  as always: know your data.  @geneteics_diva

Comment: thanks, I'm new to this and am still learning :-) I appreciate the feed back. Would it be beneficial to use "$" as a terminating anchor on "0 0"..such as 'sed -i e '1,5d;/^0 0$/,$d' genetics '

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35946/discussion-between-tink-and-geneteics-diva).

Comment: OK - yes,, it would be; but from the sample data it's not clear whether you expect any trailing space after the second 0 ... :)

Answer (score 0):

`perl` has a nice feature, called the range operator. It lets you do something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

while ( <DATA> ) { 
    print if 6 ... /0 0/;
}

__DATA__
51 0 0 5  
0 0.0 0.0 0  
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8  
1, 2  
0.998 0.567  
3, 2 Rs12345  
0.7 0.2  
3, 2 Rs31256  
0.56 0.311  
3, 2 Rs25691  
0 0  
012.1313010310 0.1213212 0.2121331321
0.0121654564 0.254564564 0.25678646 
0.02154 0.2485674354 0.2434
```

You can test for being between two regular expressions, line numbers or a mix.

Although, looking at it, perhaps it's simpler to just:

```
while ( <DATA> ) { 
    next unless $. > 5; 
    last if /0 0/;
    print;
}
```

Handily - you can do this with the `-p` flag, to make it a one liner:

```
perl -pe 'next unless $. > 5; last if /0 0/' your_file
```

Because we're using `last` it aborts processing (and stops reading the file).

`-p` is a `perl` option that make it behave a bit like `sed` - it transforms a line, and prints the line afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -i -e '1,5d' -e '/0 0/,$d
```

if the line containing "0 0" is not at a fixed location.